# Assertion Error while using Scala future with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, future, assertions

I have been using spark code inside scala future.
I am facing string error like `Assertion Failed <None>`.
This comes encapsulated on Boxed error.

Each time stack trace starts with sqlContext.udf.register line.
When I put synchonized block around udf register statement, Error goes away.

- Scala version - 2.10.8
- Spark - 1.6.0

Comment: perhaps you can add an MVCE...

Comment: We suggest you to add a [mcve]